# User movement speed calculation algorithm

Tags: android, gps, sensors

There is no algorithm to calculate user's movement speed based on GPS or acceleration sensor of cell phone, which can detect speed in a small area with higher accuracy.

I'm still looking for this code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.